# Storing form data in PHP vars using AJAX, to modify MySQL queries

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, datepicker

I am struggling trying to figure out how to implement a jquery UI date range form that will allow the modification of MySQL queries according to the inputted date range. Ideally, I would like to make my date range form introduce the new query data dynamically, without having to reload the page. I realize that the best and simplest way to do this is to use AJAX to send the form data to a backend PHP file. However, I am confused over how to use AJAX to modify existing queries. In my main front-end file, I have a date range form as follows:

```
        <form id="myForm" action="#" method="post" name="myform">
            <input type="text" class = "datepicker" id="txtStartDate" placeholder = "Start Date" style = "width : 85px; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 1mm;"/>
            <br />
            <input type="text"class = "datepicker" id="txtEndDate" placeholder = "End Date" style = "width : 85px; margin-left: 10px;"/>
            <br />
            <input type = "button" name = "submit" value = "Go" style = "margin-left: 10px;"/>
        </form>
```

I am clearly yet to write the AJAX function, but thought it would help to show the MySQL query I would like to modify to include a date range feature. Here is what it looks like before the date range variables have been set:

```
SELECT project, participant, reel, machine, qc_gsr, qc_hr, qc_acz, qc_bre 
    FROM rtcdb.session 
    WHERE site = 'ORL001';
```

And this is what I would like it to look like after the date range PHP variables have been set:

```
SELECT project, participant, reel, machine, qc_gsr, qc_hr, qc_acz, qc_bre 
    FROM rtcdb.session 
    WHERE site = 'ORL001' 
    AND download_date >= '$start_date' 
    AND download_date <= '$end_date';
```

So all in all, I would like to use AJAX to send form date to a back end PHP script that either modifies or switches MySQL query-usage in the original file to select in terms of the set date-range. Thank you very much for viewing this question and for your insight. It is valuable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#myForm").submit(function () { //Ajax event handler on submit
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        url: "pathToYourScript.php",
        success: function (response) {
            //Warn user everything went okay
        },
        error: function () {
            //Tell there's been an error
        }
    });
});
```

In your PHP, just check if the $start_date and $end_date are set. If positive then switch query (make sure to use prepared statements by the way).

If you don't need the callbacks in the Ajax you can even use $.post() method. Everything you need is in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).

Answer (score -1):

Use this jquery code

$("#myForm").submit(function(){

```
$.ajax({
url  : "data.php",
type : "POST",   //(POST or GET it depends up on your form action)    
dataType : "JSON",
data : $(this).serialize(),
success : function (data)
 { alert("form submission is successfull");  } , 
error : function () { alert("something went wrong");}

});
});
```

In php file try to get the date using POST or GET automatical global variable and then pass it to the sql query as a parameter .Use any good php drivers such as pdo for avoiding sql injection .

Comment: -1 This is my answer but with json datatype added, which isn't explicitly needed here.